# Join our newsletter?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions

Is not the phrase 'Join our newsletter' wrong? Newsletter is a communication medium, right? Like a newspaper, or an email. So, it should ideally be 'subscribe to our newsletter' or 'sign up for our newsletter'?

Comment: Yes that does sound peculiar.  Where did you come across it?

Answer (score 1):

Good observation. Upon investigation I've found it used by [newsletters](http://socialtriggers.com/) I'm subscribed to.

> **Join** our free weekly newsletter

Looking at the [definitions](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/join) for join I don't see any way this usage of the term could be correct.

An [alternative usage](http://www.twentyonepilots.com/mailing-list) of join I have seen, that is correct is - "***join*** the mailing list".

> [**join**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/join) (verb)
>
> Become a member or employee of.
>
> *‘she joined the department last year’*

Maybe arbitrarily swapping newsletter for mailing list is what leads to this error.

Comment: I think Andre is wholly right.

Comment: What about "Congress joined the White House in condemning these remarks?" I think you can make the case that "newsletter" is being used to stand for the subscribers to the newsletter, just as" White House" is being used to stand for the current President.

Comment: I would argue that "join our newsletter" is, for marketing purposes, an informal shortening of "join the group of people who receive our newsletter," in which case it is an accurate usage of the term.